# call start activity for result inside fragment class

Tags: android

I am trying to add import contact functionality to my application. i just implement import contact function inside fragment class. this function is working perfectly if device has under android 4.0. whenever i am trying with android 4.1.2, contact page get open, but suddenly it force to close the application. when i try open application again the contact is appear.

```
`enter code here`

Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
        getActivity().startActivityForResult(it, 100);
        getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, it);
        getActivity().finish();
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
            return;

        Contact ct = handleResultFromContactActivity(data);

        EditText name = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(ct.name);

        EditText primary = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.primary);
        primary.setText(ct.phone);

    }
```

Comment: what "handleResultFromContactActivity" does??
can u check if anything returned null and u r trying to use it...

Comment: bhavana- i just wrote handleResultFromContactActivity to get contact details from Contact. its perfectly working below andrios version level 4.0